# Pygame does not recognize K_SPACE while K_UP and K_LEFT are being pressed

Tags: python, input, pygame

I've created a small application isolating the problem that changes the color of the screen when the spacebar is pressed. No other combinations of the arrow keys cause this problem. When I use a key other than the spacebar this problem does not occur. Code for the application is posted below.

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

# Set window size and title, and frame delay
surfaceSize = (600, 500) 
windowTitle = 'Game' 
frameDelay = 0.02
color = "white"

# Create the window
surface = pygame.display.set_mode(surfaceSize, 0, 0)
pygame.display.set_caption(windowTitle)

# Loop forever
while True:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      #Quit Game
      if(event.type == QUIT):
         pygame.quit()
         sys.exit()
      if(event.type == KEYDOWN):
         if(event.key == K_SPACE):
            if(color == "white"):
               color = "black"
            else:
               color = "white"

   # Refresh the display
   surface.fill(pygame.Color(color))
   pygame.display.update()

   # Set the frame speed by pausing between frames
   time.sleep(frameDelay)
```

Sorry if this question was already asked I looked for a while and couldn't seem to find it.

Comment: Does this only affect your application or does the spacebar not work with K_UP and K_LEFT in all programs, such as notepad? If it doesn't work anywhere, it might be a [keyboard ghosting](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx) issue.

Comment: got the same problem in every application, weired

Comment: This is not a pygame problem, but a problem with your keyboard, as @DavidReeve already said. You can't solve this in your python code. Sorry, but your keyboard just sucks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use something more along the lines of:

...

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            pass
```